# Expandable ListView OnClick

Tags: java, android, onclick, expandablelistview

I have got MainActivity.java, SecondActivity.java and MyExpandableAdapter.java for my ExpandableListView. I am trying to on my child item click go to the SecondActivity. But I really dont know how to do that. I have tryed to add  `startActivity(new Intent(this(), SecondActivity.class));` to my OnClickListener in my MyExpandableAdapter.java but it does not work. Please help me :)

Here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
     ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
     expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
     expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
     expandableList.setClickable(true);
     setGroupParents();
     setChildData();
     MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("Android");
        parentItems.add("Core Java");
        parentItems.add("Desktop Java");
        parentItems.add("Enterprise Java");
    }

    public void setChildData() {

        // Android
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Core");
        child.add("Games");
        childItems.add(child);


        // Core Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Apache");
        child.add("Applet");
        child.add("AspectJ");
        child.add("Beans");
        child.add("Crypto");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Desktop Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Accessibility");
        child.add("AWT");
        child.add("ImageIO");
        child.add("Print");
        childItems.add(child);


        // Enterprise Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("EJB3");
        child.add("GWT");
        child.add("Hibernate");
        child.add("JSP");
        childItems.add(child);
    }

}
```

MyExpandableAdapter.java(you can see in my public void OnClick toast message, it works but as I said, I want to go to the SecondActivity, onChildItemClick)

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;


    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

My SecondActivity is empty :)

I appreciate every answer, thank you!

Comment: Can you show me your onClickListener?.

Comment: My onClickListener is in MyExpandableAdapter.java convert.View.setOnClickListener ..etc

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 @Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

to

```
 @Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for asnwer, but look to MyExpandableAdapter.java public void OnClick. How I can do OnClick go to the SecondActivity? It say "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){"

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityName.class);                      
context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: The scope of listener is not the same of the scope for the rest of your class. context takes the place of this. startActivity(intent) is the same as this.startActivity(intent) and in the scope of your listener startActivity is not part of this.

Comment: The context I was talking about is the context of the activity which should be pass as a parameter in the adapter's constructor.